# Keep flutter sensors listening on locked screen

Tags: dart, flutter, sensors

I've been working with the flutter sensors plugin and works pretty well until I lock the screen.
What I'm currently doing is listening the accelerometer events and create a post request after that.
I need to do this even with the screen locked, or even better, with the app running in background.
Do I need to create a MethodChannel and go native? or there is any way to do this with flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to use platform channels considering you want to do this in the background. This would require operating on a separate isolate. There is an article [listed in the documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) though I know others have had issues with it functioning on iOS and it's using objective c rather than swift.